# Do you know a database written in Perl with DBI interface?

Tags: database, perl, dbi

Do you know a database written purely in Perl with DBI interface?
Or what can be used if there is no MySql or Postgresql installed and I want to use Perl only?

Thank you.

Ok, I just wanted something that can be used with Catalyst.

Comment: Can you please clarify your goals?  Is pure-Perl what's important to you, or is zero-installation important?

Comment: If you're wanting to test something in the absence of Pg, or MySQL take a look at [this test script in Fey::Test](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DROLSKY/Fey-Test-0.07/lib/Fey/Test/SQLite.pm)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV) is a simple DBD implementation that uses Text::CSV to persist data to CSV files.

Answer (score 17):

What about SQLite? [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite)

Comment: I voted this answer up, but SQLite answers the second part of the question, but not the first part.  The question asked for a *database* written in Perl.  SQLite is implemented in C.  I'm assuming that the poster wants something pure-perl that can be deployed without any dependencies, like Apache Derby for Java (http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Comment: There are two questions there.  The first is about a database written in Perl.  The second is more general.  Frank's answer works for the second just fine.

Comment: short of clarification, I'd guess the zero-installation is more important and this is the answer being looked for.

Comment: DBD::SQLite doesn't have any Non-Perl external dependencies.  It includes the C source with it.

Answer (score 8):

That depends greatly on what you consider "database".

If you just want something to store your data, there's a number of Perl databases avialable. Some are listed here: http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/09/12/embedded.html

- Tie::File
- Berkley DB
- SQLite

  **Please note that despite "SQLite is written in C" comments I saw here, the article explicitly states**:

  > Conveniently, the DBI-driver for
  >   SQLite, DBD::SQLite, already contains
  >   the database engine itself as part of
  >   the module - so installing this module
  >   is all that is required to be able to
  >   use SQLite from Perl.

**However, NONE of the above is a real database engine, supporting transactions etc..., although some allow SQL-like query language access**

I'm not aware of any real database engines implemented in Perl.

Comment: I found one but it does not have DBI interface.

Comment: @Aftershock: please edit your question to be more specific about what you need and what your limitations are. Currently everyone is just trying to guess, which doesn't help anyone. :)

Comment: Well, I just wanted to discover my options. I consider to use Catalyst and it need a database as far as I know. I guess it may help others who look for a pure Perl database.

Comment: Aftershock: With all due respect, I don't think you actually want a pure-Perl database. Any non-trivial query would be dog-slow. DBs are one of the few things where you really need the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Perl rule 34:

> If you can imagine it, there's a DBD
>   module for it ;)

http://search.cpan.org/search?m=module&q=DBD::&s=1

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no database in pure perl that is *relational*, it's not really economical; you might look in ACME on CPAN.

Essentially you have two choices: a pure perl module that provides a DBD package that wraps around, for example .txt, .csv, or .xml files.

If there is none, you could also implement a BDB/DBM style system of your own using pure perl, much like Ken Thompson did in C with DBM. It however, wouldn't be as complex as having SQL based relational database.

If you expect to use SQL, use an SQL based database.

Answer (score 0):

**[DBD::DBM](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::DBM)** is a pure Perl database driver which is part of *DBI* itself since version 1.42 (April 2004). It can work with a variety of different database formats using the respective modules, e.g. [BerkleyDB](https://metacpan.org/pod/BerkeleyDB) or [SDBM_File](https://metacpan.org/pod/SDBM_File) (core module).

One needs to combine this with [MLDBM](https://metacpan.org/pod/MLDBM) to get a usable database (otherwise ony two columns per table are supported).

The documentation of DBD::DBM is quite extensive and provides a good overview of the different options and how to set it up.